# How secure is "un-firewalled" host-only virtual box adapter?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Here is my configuration using with Virtual Box:

1. Windows 7 host;
2. Mac OSX guest;
3. Guest does not need internet connection;
4. Guest needs to share a folder with host.
5. Guest uses host-only Virtual Box Adapter.

How secure is it to simply disable Windows firewall for the host-only Virtual Box Adapter knowing that:

1. Guest is launched locally on my machine;
2. Guest is launched manually and occasionally (once a day) and then shut down.

Comment: is your host directly connected to the internet or a larger network, or just a local lan?

Comment: Install nmap on the guest and start pentesting;-)

Comment: Host is as "normal computer" so connected to a work network with internet access.